# Salesforce, Apex, SOQL, SELECT with INCLUDES

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

What is wrong at this code in Apex?

```
String states = 'California,New York';
List<Account> lstACC = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState FROM Account WHERE BillingState INCLUDES (:states) LIMIT 10];
```

In Developer Console is an Error: **"BillingState FROM Account WHERE BillingState INCLUDES (:states)^ERROR at Row:1:Column:50 includes or excludes operator only valid on multipicklist field"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution:

```
Set<String> setStates = new Set<String>();
setStates.add('California');
setStates.add('New York');
List<Account> lstACC = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState 
                        FROM Account 
                        WHERE BillingState IN :setStates 
                        LIMIT 10];
```

Wrong:

```
setStates: {'California','New York'}
```

Right:

```
setStates: {California,New York}
```

**Apostrophes are in addition.**
OR

```
String states = 'California,New York';
List<String> listStates = states.split(',');
List<Account> lstACC = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState 
                        FROM Account 
                        WHERE BillingState IN :listStates 
                        LIMIT 10];
```

Wrong:

```
String states = '\'California\',\'New York\'';
```

Right:

```
String states = 'California,New York';
```

**SOQL injection is in addition.**

Answer (score 1):

The text of the error shows the problem:

> includes or excludes operator only valid on multipicklist field

`BillingState` is not a multi-select picklist. Use `IN` rather than `INCLUDES` to match against the collection.

Note additionally that a comma-separated string is not a valid collection to match against. Create a `List<String>` or `Set<String>` to use in your matching condition.

Comment: Ok, thank you. With IN is without errors. But it return nothing.
What shape should the variable states be in?
`String states = 'California,New York';
String states = '(California,New York)';
String states = '\'California\',\'New York\'';
String states = '(\'California\',\'New York\')';`
Or something else? Because it return nothing.

Comment: List of String this:
`List<String> states = new List<String>{'California','New York'};`
and also this:
`List<String> states = new String[]{'California','New York'};`
is with error in SELECT:
**Invalid bind expression type of List<String> for column of type String**
`//-----------------------------------------------------------------------`
For set 
`Set<String> states = new Set<String>{'California','New York'};`
is similar error:
**Invalid bind expression type of Set<String> for column of type String**
SELECT with IN nothing return. Any Idea?

Comment: This is OK, return results:
`SELECT Id, Name, BillingState 
FROM Account 
WHERE BillingState IN ('California','New York') //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------`
But this return nothing:
`String states = '/'California/',/'New York/'';
SELECT Id, Name, BillingState 
FROM Account 
WHERE BillingState IN (:states)` Why? I don't understand.